# Raster Clip by Polygon Log Error

Tags: qgis, raster, clip

When running the "clip raster by mask layer" tool, I come across this error and I am unsure on what to do with it. I have tried researching this problem and found a few solutions that worked for others, but those solutions aren't working for me. Any ideas on how to fix this?

[image]

Comment: I tried with high compression and it gets stuck at 47% and stayed there for 2 hours. The raster I am trying to clip is only about 38,000 KB and I have had no problem clipping raster's of this size and larger in the past?

Comment: It looks like you havent set an extent, is says extent:None. Maybe it is trying to create a huge raster. Set an extent